# Custom Geotool function that access a GeoServer's Datastore

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I'm following this tutorial to implement a custom Geotools function:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html

I want to implement a custom Geotools function that should access a GeoServer's DataStore. Could anyone please guide me to the code of connecting to a Datastore?

What I have tried is to access directly to the DB using the following code:

```
public static Connection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spatialdbnew";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "postgres", "postgres"); //use postgres username to skip row-level security to enhance performance

        /*
         * Add the geometry types to the connection.
         */
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conn).addDataType("geometry",
                (Class<? extends PGobject>) Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conn).addDataType("box3d",
                (Class<? extends PGobject>) Class.forName("org.postgis.PGbox3d"));

        return conn;
    }
```

What I want is to access to the DB using the Geoserver's Datastore.

Comment: please add what you have already tried to the question

Comment: Hi Ian, question is updated.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide information about the error or unwanted behavior that you have encountered.

Comment: read [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GeoServer-Catalog-WPS-td5038400.html) for accessing the catalog containing the datastores

Comment: Hi JGH, thaks for your comment. This is great for a WPS custom porcess, but how to do the same for a custom Geotools function?, how to have an instance from the Catalog object?